# Is it possible to use a c++ library from an older c++ version?

Tags: c++, json, c++17

So I'm trying to use JSON as a file format for my c++ project. But I cant find a library for C++17. There are a few(nlohmann/json,RapidJSON) for older versions, such as C++11 but I don't know if it's possible to use an older one. Can I do this?

Comment: What makes you think that nlohmann/json won't work for you? Consider that a library like `<cstdlib>` is from C.

Comment: `open()` is from the early 1970s and it still works, amazingly.

Comment: Im kinda confused now because the nlohmann/json was made with c++11 and im using c++17 isnt that a problem and if not how would I make that work?

Comment: If you update your IDE, do all your old projects stop working too? Or when you update your GPU drivers, do games from 3 years ago just stop working (snarky retorts aside)? It will be worth looking into what an update to the C++ standard means/entails.

Comment: https://github.com/nlohmann/json is header only. You clone their repo (download it), include it in your project and you're done.

Comment: If you're compiling the library from source, it will likely work.  If you're trying to link to a precompiled object file or DLL that was produced by an earlier version of your compiler (or a different compiler entirely), your chances of success are much smaller, probably zero.

Comment: Visual Studio 2015 to 2019 are binary compatible with each other but not compatible with any version of VS prior and likely only compatible with mingw for libraries that stick to using `c` only. Related: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/binary-compat-2015-2017?view=msvc-160](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/binary-compat-2015-2017?view=msvc-160)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

C++ versions are *largely* backwards compatible with prior versions. Any incompatibility are (usually) done for a specific purpose and with some degree of deprecation or the like.

So broadly speaking, a C++11 library (header-only or compiled) will compile under a C++17 compiler. There are times when this will fail, but they're usually around specific library types (like `std::auto_ptr` or somesuch).

For compiled libraries, ABI can be an issue (which means you may need to recompile them, which requires the source code). But for header-only libraries, this isn't a problem, since you're *always* compiling them.